# How to use parametres from differents models in the same View in ASP MVC 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

I have a partial view that inherit from a Model View 'FlowModelView' because I am using a list from this model.

I want to use parametres from another model 'Gamme'.

When I try this,,,the statement is always underline in Red.

This is the Partial view :

```
<%@  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel.Gamme>" %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%></div>


         <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(Model.Gamme=>Model.Gamme.Nbr_Passage) %></div>

        </fieldset>
         <% } %>
```

this the FlowViewModel :

```
public class FlowViewModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; }
        //public List<Poste> PostesItems { get; set; }
        public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }

        public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGamme{ get; set; }

        public int SelectedPoste { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the Gamme Model :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Gamme
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("Profile_Ga")]
        public string ID_Gamme { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("Poste")]
        public string ID_Poste { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int Nbr_Passage { get; set; }
        public string Last_Posts { get; set; }
        public string Next_Posts { get; set; }

        public virtual Poste Poste { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile_Ga Profile_Ga { get; set; }

    }
and this the controller but contains some errors :


  public class AnouarController : Controller
    {



        //
        // GET: /Anouar/

         public ActionResult Gestion()
         {
            var model = new FlowViewModel()
            { YourGammeModel = new Gamme(){

        public string ID_Gamme { get; set; }

        public string ID_Poste { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int Nbr_Passage { get; set; }
        public string Last_Posts { get; set; }
        public string Next_Posts { get; set; }

        public virtual Poste Poste { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile_Ga Profile_Ga { get; set; }

            }};

             return PartialView();

         }




    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you sent me yesterday, you're rendering Gestion as a partial within another view, so this controller action isn't actually hit. You need to change `Index.aspx` where it says

`Html.RenderPartial("Gestion")`

to

`Html.RenderAction("Gestion", "Anouar", Model)`

and change the controller action to this:

```
public ActionResult Gestion(FlowViewModel model)
{
    model.YourGammeModel = new Gamme();

    return PartialView(model);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks,,,but when i change 'RenderPartial',,,the Null exception of yesterday returns

Comment: OK I've gone back into that chat room

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check by using the following in the view page

```
<%@  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel.GaItems>" %>
```

or if you require only `Gamme` model, you have to use the following

```
 <%@  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.Gamme>" %>
```

Comment: thx,,,but how will I call the pramateres in the View :<%: Html.EditorFor(Model=>Model.Nbr_Passage) %> i try this but not working

Comment: As Giorgio pointed out, you can try by a Imports statement. are you able to get the properties of Gamme by using `Model.` via the intellisense. Imports can be like this `<%@ Imports Namespace="MvcApplication2.Models" %>`.

Comment: I will use 2 models and when I call parametre from a model,,,how he will know which model called?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Gamme member to the FlowViewModel you pass in the view and then use that. 
Only one model can be passed to a view (you can pass additional data using the ViewBag if you want).
So, or you extend the FlowViewModel or you use a the Gamme class ad the model to your view

```
@using MvcApplication2.Models.Gamme
```

or

```
public class FlowViewModel
{

    [Key]
    public string IDv { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; } 
    public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
    public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }
    //here is the gamme member
    public Gamme YourGammeModel {get;set;}

    public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }

    public int SelectedGamme{ get; set; }

    public int SelectedPoste { get; set; }
}
```

you initialize the model

```
var model = new FlowViewModel(){ YourGammeModel = new Gamme(){...}};
```

and use the gamme property inside the flowviewmodel :

```
<% Model.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage %>
```

Comment: thx but I am not using Razor ,,,and i try this <%using MvcApplication2.Models.Gamme %> but not working

Comment: I've edited the response. The same concept applies also to non razor views. You have to choose one model you want to pass and then use that.You can nest into the main model as many other objects you want. In your case you will add a Gamma member within the flowviewmodel.

Comment: I know that,,,but I want to use the FlowViewModel because i will use it later in other parametres where i need a call from differents models

Comment: the intialize is in the controller ?

Comment: it's where you create the model returned to the view. Inside your action method.

Comment: If you follow the example above, in the ActionResult you should do Gestion() { var model = new FlowViewModel() { YourGammeModel = new Gamme(){...}};

Comment: And then change 

`<div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(Model.Gamme=>Model.Gamme.Nbr_Passage) %></div>`

to

`<div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage) %></div>`

Comment: Thanks @ColmPrunty and Giorgio,,I follow your instructions but there still some errors in the Controller.
Please Check my UPDATE, I add the controller code

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in this line:

```
<div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(Model.Gamme=>Model.Gamme.Nbr_Passage) %></div>
```

you wrote lambda expression `Model.Gamme=>Model.Gamme.Nbr_Passage` but should wrote `g=>g.Nbr_Passage` where g is of type `Gamme`

And change type of view to:

```
<%@ Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.Ga‌​mme>" %>
```

Comment: it is model of this partialview <%@  Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel.Gamme>" %>

Comment: I try it but he didn't know the 'Gamme'. This is the error : The type name 'Gamme' does not exist in the type 'MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel'

Comment: You have error in type defenition of view. I Update my answer

Comment: And the FlowViewModel ! when it s gone,,,others paramaters needs it cause errors !

Comment: It is not work in that way. You should define what is model of your partial view. Is it Gamme or FlowViewModel.

Comment: This is the problem and the subject of the post. I have to use them both because the Partial View is a mixte of 2 or 3 models